# How can I set the margin of a PowerPoint TextBox with Apache POI?

Tags: java, apache-poi, powerpoint

I have an application which creates a power point presentation with Apache POI. I have some text boxes, and **I need to set the left and right margin of this text boxes to 0**.
Hypothetically it would be just these two lines:

```
xslfTextParagraph.setLeftMargin(0.0d);
xslfTextParagraph.setRightMargin(0.0d);
```

However this does not seem to work for me.

Relevant code snippet:

```
TextBox<XSLFShape, XSLFTextParagraph> textShape = shapeGroup.createTextBox();
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
textShape.setAnchor(rect.getBounds2D());
XSLFTextParagraph xslfTextParagraph = textShape.getTextParagraphs().get(0);
xslfTextParagraph.setLeftMargin(0.0); // <- This does not change the margin of the textbox
xslfTextParagraph.setRightMargin(0.0); // <- This does not change the margin of the textbox
XSLFTextRun r = xslfTextParagraph.addNewTextRun();
r.setText("Some text");
r.setFontColor(new Color(0,0,0));
r.setFontSize(14.0);
r.setBold(true);
```

Java version: 1.8,
Apache POI version: 5.0.0

Do you have any suggestion how could I set the margins to zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you want setting the body properties of the text body. Those have top-, bottom-, left- and right-inset properties.

But to get those, a `XSLFTextShape` is needed instead of the `TextBox<XSLFShape, XSLFTextParagraph>` interface.

```
...
  XSLFTextShape textShape = (XSLFTextShape)shapeGroup.createTextBox();
  Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
  textShape.setAnchor(rect);
  XDDFTextBody textBody = textShape.getTextBody();
  XDDFBodyProperties bodyProperties = textBody.getBodyProperties();
  bodyProperties.setTopInset(0d);
  bodyProperties.setBottomInset(0d);
  bodyProperties.setLeftInset(0d);
  bodyProperties.setRightInset(0d);
...
```

Complete example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.sl.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.text.*;

import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Color;

public class CreatePPTXGroupShape {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  SlideShow slideShow = new XMLSlideShow();

  Slide slide = slideShow.createSlide();

  int groupLeft = 100;
  int groupTop = 50;
  int groupWidth = 200;
  int groupHeight = 100;
  int groupPadding= 10;

  GroupShape shapeGroup = slide.createGroup();
  shapeGroup.setInteriorAnchor(new Rectangle(groupLeft, groupTop, groupWidth, groupHeight));
  shapeGroup.setAnchor(new Rectangle(groupLeft+groupPadding, groupTop+groupPadding, groupWidth-groupPadding, groupHeight-groupPadding));
  
  int x = groupLeft+20;
  int y = groupTop+20;
  int width = 100;
  int height = 20;

  XSLFTextShape textShape = (XSLFTextShape)shapeGroup.createTextBox();
  Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
  textShape.setAnchor(rect);
  XDDFTextBody textBody = textShape.getTextBody();
  XDDFBodyProperties bodyProperties = textBody.getBodyProperties();
  bodyProperties.setTopInset(0d);
  bodyProperties.setBottomInset(0d);
  bodyProperties.setLeftInset(0d);
  bodyProperties.setRightInset(0d);
  
  XSLFTextParagraph xslfTextParagraph = textShape.getTextParagraphs().get(0);
  XSLFTextRun r = xslfTextParagraph.addNewTextRun();
  r.setText("Some text");
  r.setFontColor(new Color(0,0,0));
  r.setFontSize(14.0);
  r.setBold(true);

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("CreatePPTXGroupShape.pptx");
  slideShow.write(out);
  out.close();
 }
}
```

Comment: I can confirm that this works like a charm! This is exactly what I needed. Great, detailed answer. You deserve a medal, thank you!